# Python Hw, bisection Method

Tags: python, bisection

Part A - Bisection Method
Write a function called bisection(n, p) that asks the user to enter a mathematical function f(x)
and two boundary points in order to solve for r such that f(r) = 0 using bisection method.
The function terminates when the solution r is found or when the maximum number of iterations
n is reached (default n = 100), whichever occurs first.

```
def bisection(n = 100, p = 0.0001):
  # code goes below

  fx = input("f(x) = ")
  a = float(input("Boundary A: "))
  x = a
  fa = eval(fx)

  b = float(input("Boundary B: "))
  x = b
  fb = eval(fx)

  i = 0

  if (fa * fb >= 0):
    print("Bisection method fails")
    return
  while(i < n):
    m = a + b / 2
    x = m
    fm = eval(fx)


    if(fm * fa < 0):
      a = a
      b = m
    if (fm * fb < 0):
      a = m
      b = b
    i = i + 1
    if (fm == 0):
      return m




  pass
```

When I input:  f(x) = x - 1
Boundary A: 0
Boundary B: 3

No answer is printed so I'm very confused?!

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: Why are you confused?  `-1 * 3` is less than 0 so the `print` function is never called

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this code. For some reason you defined p and never passed it again, I assume it stands for epsilon. You defined midpoint as

> a+b/2

which is equivalent to

> a+(b/2)

but you need

> (a+b)/2

.
Statement

> if (fm == 0):

this statement would probably never run because it is hard to get that close to a root for a few iterations.

Instead, use

> if (abs(fm<p)):

Modified code

```
def bisection(n = 250, p = 10**-6):
  # code goes below

    fx = input("f(x) = ")
    a = float(input("Boundary A: "))
    x = a
    fa = eval(fx)
    b = float(input("Boundary B: "))
    x = b
    fb = eval(fx)

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        m = (a + b)/2
        x = m
        fm = eval(fx)


        if(fm * fa < 0):
            a = a
            b = m
        elif (fm * fa > 0):
            a = m
            b = b
        elif (abs(fm<p)):
            return m




print(bisection())
```

Output:

```
f(x) = x - 1
Boundary A: 0
Boundary B: 3
1.0
```

Comment: Why is there a (n + 1), could you explain it just a tiny bit?

Comment: In order to get n iterations, you can either say i in range (0, n) or i in range (1, n+1) they're exactly the same for this problem. Note that the lower bound is included and the upper bound is excluded in python.

Comment: What if Boundary A is larger than Boundary B? for example Boundary A: 1 and Boundary B: 0?